# Drupal: using Rules, apply pathauto settings to node

Tags: drupal

I need to use Rules to create a rule that updates the path for the currently saved node according to the settings pathauto uses. The conditions for the rule are content type and that one of several fields have been modified.

Comment: If you use the rule to delete the alias does it just leave that blank and not repopulate on that save? Just curious.

Comment: @doublejosh - it depends on the trigger. If you set it to 'After save' and you delete the path, all that's left is a raw system path. If you set it to 'Before save' pathauto will populate a new alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't use Rules to interact with Pathauto, but you can use Rules action: "Create or delete a content's URL alias" which basically does the same thing as pathauto (i.e., lets you use tokens to create paths).

So just create a new rule, add those filters to the IF (i.e., if content has type blahblah and (xxx field has been modified OR yyy field has been modified OR zzz field has been modified)), and use the "Create or delete a content's URL alias" action to change the alias, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Pathauto already automatically applies its settings. You don't need the rules module.

Comment: You do if you have complex rules for setting the path